# How to format code in Blogger

Tags: blogger, formatting

I am writing one article on Blogger, There I am unable to format code. The code I am writing is looking like simple text. 
The site name https://www.blogger.com/
I am using `<div class="yourClassName"> code here </div>` tag to show formatted code, which is giving below output

Using:

[image]

output: 
[image]

How can I show code in proper way

Comment: What is the definition of "yourClassName"?

Answer (score 1):

In Blogger's Post-editor, make sure that you have selected Show HTML literally under the Options > Compose-mode sidebar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What Blogger shows is HTML; you can use the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags as you would in normal HTML.

It's been a while since I last worked with Blogger, but IIRC it has an editor that lets you use HTML directly. Your `<div class="yourClassName">` should work if you put it there, if `yourClassName` has been defined properly. Which, in the case of computer programming code, usually assumes a monospaced font, among other preferences.

There are a number of resources that can help you format; I found [this one](http://codeformatter.blogspot.com/) that uses only `<pre>` and `<code>` to get your code in code formatting.

There is also [this old, off-topic question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/679189/812149) that recommends various online resources. Since it's old, you'll have to experiment a little to see what still works.